# database produce result and number of other fields in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say we have a table in our database (It's simple in the example in reality we will have
more tables, attributes and connections between them)

```
book(book_id, name, attr1, attr2, attr3)
```

So with a search form, user creates an url with get parameters which produce some results.
In a sideSearch form in the result page, i want to have the count of the book names, attr1, attr2 etc that meet the search criteria. For example if user wants attr3 = 'something' i want in my sideSearch number of other fields that have attr3 = 'something'

```
book_name_1   num_1
book_name_2   num_2
attr1_1       num_1
attr1_2       num_2
```

In my application book_names and attrs are known. The only way i can think is inside a for loop (1000-1500 repetitions) with

```
select count(*) from book where name='book_name_1' and attr3 = 'something'
```

etc. Can you think of a better way to do this? I am using php.

Comment: I guess that you would like to receive the book data and the number of results with only one query. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes but an array of number of results, for example the number of results for every book-name, for every attr1 etc, that also meets search criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do it with

```
SELECT name,COUNT(name) FROM book WHERE attr3 = 'something' GROUP BY name
SELECT attr1,COUNT(attr1) FROM book WHERE attr3 = 'something' GROUP BY attr1
SELECT attr2,COUNT(attr2) FROM book WHERE attr3 = 'something' GROUP BY attr2
```

etc. I will also have one more query for the results. So generally, i will have at about 10 queries in the page. In my application i save $from, and $where parts so i don't need to write them again, otherwise i was considering of using view tables. Please comment if you think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You might well benefit from looking at a mysql FULLTEXT index and search on those fields.  You do not mention it so -- if for no other reason -- you should try it and then discount it if it does not work. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

I had success with multi searches where we did a fulltext search, then if less than n results were found we did tag= style searches as an alternative.

Comment: As i understand, FULL TEXT is used to add all generations of the searched word, which has no use to me, because my attributes are enum types (they can have specific values), although i have them in varchar now (perhaps i'll change that later).